API calls not showing in network tab
I am using Spartacus 2211.21 and currently we have custom http interceptor as well, however when u am trying to upgrade the version to 2211.23 or later api call and even debugger is not going inside my interceptor nor api calls are going
API call should happen

The question you provided shows some effort in describing the problem, but it could be improved for clarity and to demonstrate more research effort.
